# How to stop parent div trigger while clicking child div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

How to stop parent event trigger while clicking child event?

CODE:

```
$('body').on('click', 'cs-placeholder', function(e) {
    //* Disable dropdown in modals that aren't contacts
    if( $(e.target).parents(".modal").length === 0 || $(e.target).parents("#contact").length === 1 ) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            alert('close');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    } else {
        alert('open');
        $('.cs-placeholder').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `e.stopPropagation()` inside child click handler.

Comment: Post your code, not a picture of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on('click', '.cs-placeholder', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If you want to read more on [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).